# How does FastAPI/any other backend framework handle multiple concurrent requests?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, backend, fastapi

I am trying to understand how FastAPI or for that matter any other backend framework handle multiple concurrent user requests. I have built a full stack ML Cancer Prediction app which is working great for one user but I am thinking about how it can scale and serve multiple users fundamentally. I've written my API routes in FastAPI, one of them is to handle user uploads and another to predict. Here is the code:

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    path = Path(__file__).parents[1] / "saved_images" / file.filename
    try:
        with path.open("wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", e)
    global current_filename
    current_filename = file.filename
    return {"filename": file.filename}

@app.get("/predict/")
async def predict(filename: str):
    path = Path(__file__).parents[1] / "saved_images" / filename
    path = str(path)
    models = utils.get_models_list()
    dataset_test = DatasetTest(df_single_image, 'test', 'test', transform=transforms_test)
    image = dataset_test[0]
    prediction, probs = utils.predict_single_image(image, models)
    return {"Probs": probs,
            "Prediction": prediction}
```

Running the `predict` route for each test sample/image takes about 2 minutes. I have two basic questions here:

i) What if two users simultaneously upload their images using the `upload` route? How is it handled by FastAPI?

ii) Let's say two users have their images uploaded to the filesystem and now they use the `predict` route simultaneously, how does FastAPI handle that and the main question - how does it determine which user to return which Response to(Assuming I don't have an authentication system in place, so any user can just come onto the web app and start using it)?

Also, here is the frontend component I'm using to send these requests:

```
const PredictButton = () => {
    const selectedFile = useContext(FileContext);
    const [pred, setPred] = useState(null);

    const handleUpload = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        };
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/uploadfile', requestOptions);
    }
    const handlePredict = async () => {
        await handleUpload();
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
        };
        const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/predict/?filename=${selectedFile.name}`, requestOptions);
        const data = await resp.json();
        setPred(data["Prediction"]);
    }
    return (
        <div className="predict-button">
            <button className="predict-button-button" onClick={handlePredict}>Predict!</button>
            <div className="pred">
                {pred===null ? null : (pred === 1 ? <div className="detected">Prediction: Cancer Detected</div> : <div className="no-detected">Prediction: No cancer Detected</div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me clear up these fundamental doubts.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a quick scenario how fast API handles requests concurrently and determines
wich user gets response in Multi user environment.

**Let's say** :

when two users simultaneously uploads thier images `/uploadfile/` route, `FASTAPI`  will uses `event loop` to mange concurrent request and each request is processed seperately and ensures  that the requests do not interfere with each other. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/

To give specific points on how and why :

- `FastAPI`  runs an async event loop that coordinates the async path functions, and a `threadpool (group of workers to do tasks in parallel)` for synchronous path functions
- When one user makes a request, FASTAPI doesnt wait for request to complete before handling the next one. (Its like a restaurant with multiple chefs and requests are like orders and processed concurrently by threadpool) also known as `Asynchronous Handling`
- As FASTAPI doesnt have any authentication, it treats all requests equally  but doesnt mix up the requests .If you don't have any `RBAC or authentication or user identification` mechanisms, it  will process request as `First-come First served`  Fashion.
- In `Production`, user management and Authentication is crucial to keep users data separated and secured.

Hope this helps and let us know if you have any queries!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This clears up a lot. A follow up question - what if the request by the second user gets completed first, how would `first come first serve` work? Also what if two users send requests at the exact same moment, how would `FastAPI` determine which user to send which response to since there are two responses being generated after processing of the request?

Comment: If the second user's request is processed faster, their response will be sent first, even if their request was received after the first user's request.  (its more of `Order of Completion` until there is any dependecies for the request from the user 1)

Comment: Also, If multiple users send requests at the exact same moment, FastAPI will process and respond to each request `independently` and as quickly as possible. The responses are sent back to the respective users as soon as the processing is done.

Comment: As requests are processed, FastAPI keeps track of which response belongs to which request based on the unique identifiers assigned to each request. as request processing is finished, it associated the response with corresponding request

Comment: I am afraid that what is described in the first bullet point is not entirely correct. Normal `def` functions run in an external threadpool that is then `await`ed; hence, FastAPI will still work asynchronously - it **won't** run the tasks in parallel, as mentioned above. To do that, one would need to use multiple [server workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/) (processes). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot! Just one last follow up question - what if I want to create a message queue to act as an intermediate step before sending the data to the backend(incase I need to scale in the future and add multiple servers). Could FastAPI even then be able to send the appropriate response to the appropriate user?